# Re-render child components in VueJS2

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a parent component with two child component coding-question-content and mcq-question-content. At a time only one will be on screen depending on the condition as per the code :-

```
<div v-if="currentlyActive >= 0">
    <div v-if="questions[currentlyActive].type === 'Coding'">
        <coding-question-content></coding-question-content>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <mcq-question-content></mcq-question-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

These components are reloaded each time the `questions[currentlyActive].type` changes. I want these pages to reload completely everytime `currentlyActive` changes.
`currentlyActive` is a variable which stores the index of the active question from the sidebar.

Comment: You should pass props to components.
Take a look here - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props